# How to prevent chrome from injecting content to webpage

Tags: php, google-chrome, code-injection

Recently I have discovered that my application is misbehaving in Google Chrome.

On a page with a form, after it was submitted, my application reloads page using simple method like this:

```
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

after that, page is rendered incorrectly and this content is injected to DOM

```
<div id="sbi_camera_button" class="sbi_search" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 29px; height: 27px; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 2147483647; display: none; "></div>
```

After manual page refresh everything works as expected.

I'm not sure what causing this behavior, as I'm working in closed local environment and application works fine in Firefox.

My application using following libraries (hosted locally):

- jQuery v1.7.1
- jQuery UI 1.8.16
- Bootstrap.js v 2.1.1

Can someone suggest me what can possibly cause this issue?

Comment: What Chrome extensions have you installed? Check if they're OK.

Comment: It is indeed a Chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-by-image-by-google/dajedkncpodkggklbegccjpmnglmnflm

Comment: Yes, it is a "Search by Image (by Google)", which causing it, but I'm wandering why does it interact with my POST requests

Comment: You need to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) before anyone is able to help.

Comment: It isn't interacting with your post, just adding elements to the response the browser gets.

Comment: for some reasons it is preventing page from further rendering, only if page processing time take more than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Could it be the [Search By Image plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-by-image-by-google/dajedkncpodkggklbegccjpmnglmnflm) of Chrome?

I got the hint from [that forum](http://forum.textpattern.com/viewtopic.php?pid=266344).

Comment: I have seen this post, but this issue appear to be for a while

Comment: I have the same issue with Firefox